# Реализовать функцию платной подписки на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите пожалуйста плагин платной подписки пользоватей на wordpress с русской платежной системой.
То есть нужно чтобы пользователь мог зарегистрироваться и купить доступ к контенту на сайте c CMS wordpress. Нужна именно русская платежная система.
Подскажите с какими плагинами можно такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce - плагин электронной коммерции

WooCommerce Memberships - дополнение к WooCommerce для реализации платной подписки

"Русская платежная система" - есть платежные модули под yandex, webmoney и т.д.

Comment: а там есть возможность организовать подписку на месяц например? и можно ли скрывать контент?

Comment: @Артем да. там все это есть

Comment: Подскажите который именно плагин. ПО запросу WooCommerce Memberships находит много таких плагинов с такими названиями.

Comment: @Артем https://www.woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/